# Retrieving values passed by POST method form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, ibm-midrange

I am facing some problem with **POST** method in form . I have a page A with a form with **POST** method and when i submit form it goes to page b .

Now problem is that when i do a refresh it
pop ups a alert which i don't want to come . I am using HTML and Javascript.

Is there any way to handle this refresh?

One way that i can think of is to dynamically create a hidden form on page b with the values populated in fields and for every refresh it just submits that hidden form .

Please suggest and let me know if there is some other neat work around. Thanks in advance! 
Basically i am using CGIDEV2 on AS400 platform . So when input form on page a is submitted it call abc.pgm which writes page b. Cgidev2 writes html in sections . It will write /TOP section then /REFRESHFORM. and these values will be populated in abc.pgm .

```
PAGE a
    /FORM
        <form name="input" action="abc.pgm" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
Page b 
    /TOP
    -----------------
    -------------- 
    /REFRESHFORM
    <form name="refreshinput" action="abc.pgm" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to avoid the "confirm form resubmission" alert? The usual way to do that is using the [POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern: page A would POST the form to the server, the server processes the data and then issues a 3xx redirect back to the user, triggering a GET request for page B. Thus subsequent reloads of page B would just be the usual drill, i.e. no alert message.

Comment: The url on page b would be whatever you set it to be in the redirect.

Comment: Ok thanks ! Please can you send me some link with the code in it for implementation

Comment: Well, all the "magic" here happens on the server, so that's going to be entirely dependent on what you're using on the server-side. Having no familiarity with CGIDEV2, I couldn't help you there at all, though I'm sure it's out there somewhere via Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a click event handler for a submit button, you just need to prevent default action on click.

```
$('#Submit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // submit the form using ajax
  // on success go to the page B
  ...
}
```

Comment: Actually these are old code so can't use AJAX ..have to do this with javascript

Comment: You should follow the Post/Redirect/Get pattern, that was suggested by Ultranaut, but anyway the best solution would be using of ajax.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to avoid this issue, but you can try to use an XMLHttpRequest object instead of forms. You will need to write some javascript code, but your server code will stay without changes.

See the following [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) and [example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post2).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function Submit()
{
var form = document.getElementById("data-form");
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    form.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","abc.pgm",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("userName=" + form["userName"].value + "&userPass=" + form["userPass"].value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="data-form">
    Username: <input type="text" name="userName">
    Userpass: <input type="text" name="userPass">
    <input id="submit" onclick="Submit()" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!So now if abc.pgm directs to page b and then when F5 is pressed at page b it will submit this form again ?