# How to pass value to another static page via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to pass  value to another page and read the value in the another page. I use only JavaScript and jQuery. Not use others language as PHP. I don't want to be as like `(http://www.example.com/?value=test)`. I am trying to use POST or GET method.

On first page:

```
$.post("second_page.html",{q:"test"});
window.location.replace("second_page.html");
```

On second page:

```
var location_query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = location_query.split("&");
    for (var i in vars) {
        var param = vars[i].split("=");
        params[param[0].toString()] = param[1];
    }
```

If I pass value as like `http://www.example.com/?q=test` , the second page script is read the value, but I use this line: `$.post("second.html",{q:"test"});` not read.

How to pass value from first page to another static page via JavaScript or jQuery or ajax?

Comment: The problem is that your `post` is one request, and your `location.replace` is a second request - which is a different instance. Therefore the first post data is not available in the second instance

Comment: You need to use a GET request as POST puts the parameters in the HTTP body of the request NOT the url

Comment: Following post might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544496/retrieving-values-passed-by-post-method-form

It references http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 1):

See [this post says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409029/1059101):

> POST data is data that is handled server side. And Javascript is on client side. So there is no way you can read a post data using JavaScript.

but you can use cookies to read and store values:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

[you can get it from here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme)

Try with reading the documentation and see if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Without using `GET` or `POST` you can transfer the content using HTML5 [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) or 
[Web SQL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

Answer (score 0):

$.post and $.get send AJAX request and waiting response on current page, you cant send params for next `window.location.replace` by this.

Use url get-params `window.location.replace("404.html?q=404");` and look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter) for get params on second page.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to appear params.

Comment: So, you can put params to cookie.