# How to pass values to a static HTML page

Tags: jquery, django, html

I am trying to pass a value to a static HTML page. jQuery finds the value in the table, but how do I pass it to the next page

```
$('.gobutton').bind('click', function(){
   var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td')[0].innerHTML        
   var forward = window.location.replace('{% url 'example' %}');
});
```

I tried using `sessionStorage.setItem("user_val",value)` but I cant seem to recover it on that view in any way.

`$.post('{% url 'example' %}', {"user_val":value})` method doesn't load the html page, but passes the value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925711/how-to-pass-value-to-another-static-page-via-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing

```
sessionStorage.setItem("user_val",value);
window.location.replace('{% url 'example' %}');
```

Then on `example` page I checked for existence of `user_val` with `sessionStorage.getItem` 
If `user_val` existed I launched the coded (AJAX) I need. And set `user_val` to `""`, cleaning up the memory. If `user_val` didnt exist it would launch the page like it was previously.

Answer (score 0):

create a form with a hidden input field, populate the hidden input field with your value. Bind click event to form submit and then just read the POST variable.

Comment: Sample code? It is not as easy as one button, I have many of them and they extract a value from the table and then submit it

Comment: they are dynamically populated, id rather stay way from unique id buttons here

Comment: if you create dynamically (e.g. populate from a database) you have already a unique id you could use